# How to handle multiple instances of input to one field

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a line in a multiline textbox after every information that the user enters in the TextBox in Windows form. I wont be able to determine the point to draw line as I wont know how long the user will enter information. So I am thinking of adding a  string "_______" after a button click in the code. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? Where is the user entering records? A form? A database? Also, what do you mean by "adding a "___" after a button click"? Thanks!

Comment: I agree, the question is very weird, clarify it

Comment: I just want to add a separating line between each information entered by user in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

If the user is going to be required to click a button to confirm a single entry then I don't think you should continue to store the information in the same text box & provide a visual separation with a bunch of dashes, rather move the text entered from the input to a more formatted display (set of controls).  Then the display will be separated from input. You could them allow the user to select individual input in the display to modify entry providing a nice user experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use a regular multiline textbox, printing a line of '-' characters is your best bet. Of course, you could print a line of '─' characters to make the line solid. Another alternative is to use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control, and set its [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property to the HTML you would like to display. This will allow you to append `<hr/>` whenever you want a dividing line.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing a custom control.

You could either paint the control yourself, or use an autosized label and the control's scollbars.